# Ruby on rails: wrong number of arguments (Devise and parsley-rails gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, parsley.js

Currently i have working devise form, but now i'm trying to add some client side validation with parsley-rails.
How to include 3 argument in form_for helper if i can include only 2 arguments

I'm using

```
Rails 4.1.8
ruby 2.1.5p273
```

So this is my form:

```
 <%= form_for(resource as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %>
      </div>

        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @validatable %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

        <hr>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :country_id %>
        <%= f.select(:country_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name)) %>
      </div>

        <br><br>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

and this are parsley-rails instructions: 
*And then I added the following to the form I wish to validate on*

```
 <%= form_for :user, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} do |user| %>
```

When i'm trying to include this line i always get error even after i deleted that :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} line

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Extracted source (around line #3):      

<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<div class="field">
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a comma after `resource` in `form_for(resource as: resource_name ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to include this.
This is how form_for should look like

```
<%= form_for(resource, :html => {:'data-validate' => 'parsley'}, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
....
<% end %>
```